# How to make my photo gallery and table align by their height

Tags: html, css

I want to align my table and my photo gallery on the redline how can I do that?

[Check this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzsjH.jpg)

HTML

```
<section class="first">
    <div class="column-1">
        <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-autoplay="true">
        </div>
        <div class="styled-table-div">
            <table class="styled-table">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to each other on a line are lined up;

> "vertical-align: top"